# How do I make my repositories async without affecting upper layers

Tags: async-await, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Asp.net MVC 5 application that has:

- Web UI layer
- Business Logic layer
- Data repositories layer

They are also referenced in this order. UI only accesses business logic, and business logic references repositories.

As with 99% of applications everything can and should be executed synchronously except calls into database (or other I/O expensive operations). That's why I would like to make Data layer asynchronous but without affecting upper layers to make all upper calling methods async (all the way to controller actions).

Is that possible?

### What I was thinking to do

I was thinking of changing things this way.

#### Data layer method

```
public async Task<SomeEntity> GetData()
{
    return await Task.Run<SomeEntity>(() => ...);
}
```

#### Business logic method

```
public SomeEntity GetData()
{
    return this.repo.GetData().Result;
}
```

### Questions

Does this make sense and would I actually get my code to execute in asynchronous manner?

### Update

After reading Stephen Cleary's blog post it made it more clear to me that whole *call stack* to the bottom (data layer that splits the synchronisity) is being split by the data async call hence all calls on the stack should be async and split as well.

If this thinking is correct then are my assumptions correct when I say that

> *In order to not have the whole synchronous call stack converted to async we should create a separate thread that would work asynchronously and our synchronous thread would use it.*

### Question 2

Is this assumption correct and if it is, is that the only way to keep some parts synchronous?

Comment: Aren't you going to need to wait for the data to return?  So that pretty much makes it a Synchronous task.

Comment: @Maess: Are you sure? Can you provide some web resource where this gets explained? I am awaiting my task to execute but it's true I'm later synchronously processing its results which is exactly what I intended. Why wouldn't my task execute asynchronously?

Comment: You are using the await keyword see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As with 99% of applications everything can and should be executed synchronously except calls into database.

Not at all. Anything that is I/O-based should be asynchronous.

So, the data layer does database I/O, and should be asynchronous.

The business logic layer uses the data layer, which is I/O-based, and should be asynchronous.

The UI layer uses the business logic layer, which is I/O-based, and should be asynchronous.

Of course, only those methods that are actually I/O-based should be made asynchronous; the rest should be synchronous. But I find that in data-access-heavy applications, they should be almost entirely *asynchronous*.

> Does this make sense and would I actually get my code to execute in asynchronous manner?

No. Sorry, but you should never wrap asynchronous code in `Task.Run` and block on it in an ASP.NET application. All that does is use up more threads than necessary for processing your request. It would be better to keep it all synchronous than to use multiple threads to keep it synchronous.

On ASP.NET, you *have* to allow the asynchrony to propagate through all layers in order to have asynchronous actions/handlers (and all the benefits that come with it, namely, scalability).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I/O. I'm aware of that thank you yes. That's why I said 99%. Majority of applications use database and on some rare occasions other IO as well. It could be that I exaggerated the percentage, but I'm pretty sure that this number is more than 90%.

Comment: When you say "*...only those methods that are actually I/O-based should be made asynchronous; the rest should be synchronous...they should be almost entirely asynchronous.*". Ok so you say they should be. But how does one implement them to keep just I/O intensive parts async without making other sync parts async.

Comment: When I say "I/O-based", I mean the operation as a whole. So if your data layer `GetData` is using, e.g., EF6 to talk to the database, it is I/O-based and should be `async`. Then, if your business logic layer `GetData` is using the data layer `GetData`, it is also I/O-based by transitivity. So my point is that the business logic layer is *not* synchronous; most of it is asynchronous by nature (in these types of apps, that is).

Comment: Ok Stephen. As I've read your blog post linked in [Todd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21581257/75642) which made it much clearer. I suppose I was creating a deadlock in my code (as per your post). Actually the data layer method splits execution of the whole call stack hence the whole call stack should be async. Can you also check my update.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: There are [several ways](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) to do "sync over async". You're still thinking of partitioning this horizontally but that just can't be done in a general way. The problem with the "separate thread" idea is that it only adds overhead on ASP.NET and gains you nothing.

Comment: I'm convinced that I'll stay on the sync side for now and refactor to full async when I hit a bottleneck. The whole question became more or less of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing sync with async in this manor can be dangerous as it invites deadlocks. Stephen Cleary explains this very well here:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html